# Websphere instalation v 7 Error

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, server-application

I'm trying to install websphere application server v7

I followed the steps

and when I click on next after after entering security administration password I got this error message

```
System Prerequisite Check

The system prerequisite check failed. The error messages are as follows:
 

Unable to retrieve information from the minimal service level (MSL) file of the installation.
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can use the instructions in [this IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21633246) to disable MSL checking (you'll need to substitute v70 for v80 in the property name).  I must also point out that you're trying to install a version of WAS that goes out of service in 5 months.  You may instead want to invest in installation of a more modern version of WAS like v9.